# Convert formula from CGS to SI

Tags: electromagnetism, units, si-units, unit-conversion

I'd like to convert this formula 
\begin{equation}
l^2 =\frac{c\hbar}{eH}
\end{equation}
where $l$ is a length, and $H$ is in oersted, to SI units.
I am pretty sure it uses CGS, since Oe is mentioned in the text, and its from a theory paper ([Kawabata1980](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0038-1098(80)90644-4), eq.3).

Comment: Does this post help? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269410/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a plasma physicist I use the NRL Plasma Formulary to convert between CGS and SI units. It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.nrl.navy.mil/ppd/content/nrl-plasma-formulary).

On page 18 it gives you a prescription on how to convert any formula. Remember to convert both sides of the equation. For your problem I get

$$ l^2 = \frac{\varepsilon_0 c^2 \hbar}{eH} $$

Step by step instruction:

1. Identify all the quantities in your equation (with $\alpha=10^2\mathrm{cm\;m}^{-1}$ and $\beta=10^7\mathrm{erg\;J}^{-1}$)

   - $l$ length, factor $\alpha$
   - $c$ velocity, factor $\alpha$
   - $\hbar$ action = energy $\times$ time, factor $\beta \times 1$
   - $e$ charge, factor $(\alpha \beta / 4 \pi \varepsilon_0)^{1/2}$
   - $H$ magnetic intensity, factor $(4 \pi \mu_0\beta/\alpha^3)^{1/2}$
2. Replace all quantities in the equation
   $$ \alpha^2 l^2 = \frac{\alpha c \; \beta \hbar}{(\alpha \beta / 4 \pi \varepsilon_0)^{1/2}e\;(4 \pi \mu_0\beta/\alpha^3)^{1/2}H} $$
3. Simplify
   $$ l^2 = \frac{c \; \hbar}{(1 / \varepsilon_0)^{1/2}e\;\mu_0^{1/2}H} =  \frac{\varepsilon_0 c \; \hbar}{(\varepsilon_0 \mu_0)^{1/2}eH} $$
4. Use $c = 1/\sqrt{\varepsilon_0 \mu_0}$
   $$ l^2 = \frac{\varepsilon_0 c^2 \hbar}{eH} =  \frac{\hbar}{e\mu_0 H}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear to me what's going on there, but the authors provide a useful foothold by stating (under equation 4) that the cyclotron frequency of the problem is
$$
\omega=\frac{eH}{mc},
$$
and this needs to correspond directly with [the SI expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_resonance#Cyclotron_frequency),
$$
\omega_\mathrm{SI}=\frac{eB}{m}.
$$
From here you can get the correspondence 
$$
\frac{eH}{c} \leftrightarrow (eB)_\mathrm{SI}.
$$
Taking this and running with it, you get the SI version
$$
l^2=\frac{\hbar}{eB}.
$$
This checks out dimensionally: $eB$ is a force per unit velocity, with dimensions $[F/v]=[M\,T^{-1}]$, which matches $[\hbar/l^2]$.

Moreover, this coincides with Holger's black magic (which is probably the way to go), which reduces to $l^2=\hbar/e\mu_0H$, and this coincides with $l^2=\hbar/eB$ in vacuum.

Comment: Dimensional analysis probably isn't enough to manage unit conversions when electromagnetism is involved.

Comment: @EL_DON Indeed it isn't, which is why the bulk of this answer is based on the cyclotron frequency. It's still a useful consistency check, which is why I included it.